# Reverse numbers and tick on shifted plot y-axis

Tags: plotting, ticks

Consider the graph produced by the following code

`ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[0, 100, 0.4], Table[Sin[x/4], {x, 0, 100, 0.4}]}], PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {120, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]`

What is the simplest way in which to "reverse" the y-axis such that the numbers and ticks appear on the right hand side of the line of the axis.

I have looked documentation and also here. But I can only find solutions which use a `Frame`. For reasons related to the real-world case I would like to use `ListLinePlot` with a shifted `AxesOrigin`.

I would assume there is a very simple way in which to do this which I am missing.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html) (**EXPERIMENTAL** introduced in v12.3)

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[{
    Range[0, 100, 0.4],
    Table[Sin[x/4], {x, 0, 100, 0.4}]}],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, Automatic},
  AxesOrigin -> {120, 0},
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"},
  Ticks -> {True, False}],
 Graphics[{
   AxisObject[{"Vertical", 120, {-1.1, 1.1}},
    TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip"]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob - this is just what I am looking for. I cannot believe the way to do this was so convoluted previously (as shown in @kglr's excellent solution).

Answer (score 3):

This gets you pretty close. BobH beat me to it, but I'm posting this anyway because it illustrates a few more features, like Prolog and AxisObject options. You may need to fiddle with the style a bit more, and maybe automate how ticks are generated so it can be updated easily.

```
ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[{Range[0, 100, 0.4], Table[Sin[x/4], {x, 0, 100, 0.4}]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, Automatic}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {120, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
  Ticks -> {True, False}, 
  Prolog -> 
    AxisObject[
      {"Vertical", 120}, {-1, 1}, 
      TickPositions -> {5, 5}, 
      TickLabels -> {{"-1.0", "-0.5", None, "0.5", "1.0"}}, 
      TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip", 
      TickDirection -> Right]]
```

[image]

(Using version 13.2.0)

Comment: Thanks - I have accepted @Bobs answer as he got in first. But I appreciate the additional things you added. Thank-you.

Answer (score 3):

```
WolframLanguageData["AxisObject", "VersionIntroduced"]
```

> ```
> 12.3
> ```

For versions older than V12.3, we can post-process the plot output to modify vertical axis as follows:

```
ClearAll[modifyYAxis]
modifyYAxis[tickSpecs_:Automatic, labelOffset_:10, labelAlignment_:Left] :=
  Module[{ao = Values@First@Options[#, AxesOrigin], 
     tix = Values@First@AbsoluteOptions[#, Ticks], 
     ts = tickSpecs /. Automatic -> {.02, 0}}, 
    Show[#, Ticks -> {First @ tix, 
       ReplaceAll[{a_?NumericQ, b_, _, c___} :> 
        {a, "", b /. {"" -> ts/2, _ -> ts}, c}] @ Last[tix]}, 
     Prolog -> Cases[Last @ tix, 
        {a : Except[Last @ ao], b : Except[""], ___} :> 
          Text[b, Offset[{labelOffset, 0}, {First @ ao, a}], labelAlignment]], 
     PlotRangeClipping -> False]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
llp = ListLinePlot[
    Transpose[{Range[0, 100, 0.4], Table[Sin[x/4], {x, 0, 100, 0.4}]}],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {120, 0}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, ImageSize -> 400, BaseStyle -> 16];


Row[{llp, modifyYAxis[] @ llp}, Spacer[40]]
```

[image]

Use `AxesOrigin -> {135, 1/2}` in definition of `llp` to get

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this. I have accepted @Bobs answer as it is obviously the simple route I was looking for. All be it with an experimental feature. Thanks for this pre-12.3 version. It really is crazy (at least to me) what was previously required to do such an, on the face of it, "simple" thing. I would not have know the first place to start with coding this route myself. Thanks.